# Iterate through alphabet in Swift explanation

Tags: swift, unicode, ascii

I accidentally wrote this simple code to print alphabet in terminal:

```
var alpha:Int = 97

while (alpha <= 122) {
    write(1, &alpha, 1)
    alpha += 1
}

write(1, "\n", 1)
//I'm using write() function from C, to avoid newline on each symbol
```

And I've got this output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

So, here is the question: Why does it work?
In my logic, it should display a row of numbers, because an integer variable is being used. In C, it would be a char variable, so we would mean that we point to a sign at some index in ASCII. Then:

```
char alpha = 97;
```

Would be a code point to an 'a' sign, by incrementing alpha variable in a loop we would display each element of ascii through 122nd.

In Swift though, I couldn't assign an integer to Character or String type variable. I used Integer and then declared several variables to assign UnicodeScalar, but accidentally I found out that when I'm calling write, I point to my integer, not the new variable of UnicodeScalar type, although it works! Code is very short and readable, but I don't completely understand how does work and why at all.

Has anyone had such situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it work?

This works “by chance” because the integer is stored in little-endian byte order.
The integer `97` is stored in memory as 8 bytes

```
0x61 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

and in `write(1, &alpha, 1)`, the address of that memory location is
passed to the `write` system call. Since the last parameter (`nbyte`)
is 1, the first byte at that memory address is written to the 
standard output: That is `0x61` or `97`, the ASCII code of the letter
`a`.

> In Swift though, I couldn't assign an integer to Character or String type variable.

The Swift equivalent of `char` is `CChar`, a type alias for `Int8`:

```
var alpha: CChar = 97
```

---

Here is a solution which does not rely on the memory layout and
works for non-ASCII character as well:

```
let first: UnicodeScalar = "α"
let last: UnicodeScalar = "ω"

for v in first.value...last.value {
    if let c = UnicodeScalar(v) {
        print(c, terminator: "")
    }
}

print()

// αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψω
```